# Looking for a free & usable iPhone Jabber client to connect to iChat Server in Mac OS X Server 10.5

Tags: mac-osx, iphone, xmpp

I'm running iChat server on an XServe running Mac OS X Server 10.5.  Using Apple's iChat as a client or Pidgin from a Windows box users can connect just fine.  I'm the most mobile user in the bunch, and I have an iPhone that I would like to use in order to chat with people in the office when I'm not in.

Setting aside the VPN issues for the moment (we have one, it works marvelously), is there an iPhone Jabber client (free) that will work?  I've tried several: Talkonaut, mundu IM, Monal, and IM+ Lite.  No joy.

I don't feel like forking over money to test another app when all of these claim to have the feature set I want, but don't.  If that's the case, then I'm not likely to believe their paid versions work any better.

Looking forward to hearing opinions!

Answer (score 1):

You could try Jabba is not free but cost1.59$ , it's not bad and have a gui similar to' ichat.